# Meaning of 水洗式 other than flush toilet

Tags: meaning, words, kanji, terminology

In an article about [penetrant testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dye_penetrant_inspection) ([浸透探傷検査](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B5%B8%E9%80%8F%E6%8E%A2%E5%82%B7%E6%A4%9C%E6%9F%BB)) I found the following sentence:

> 浸透液は**水洗式**でハケ塗りとし，極力溶接部以外に浸透液が付着しないようにすること．

In this kind of test, a penetrant liquid is used on a surface (in this case a weld area, 溶接部) to check if it has defects.

[Here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/116550/meaning/m0u/) I read that 水洗式 refers to a flush toilet, but in this context it doesn't make much sense to me. Could it refer to a drainage outlet or something similar? I mean something used during the test to collect the dripping of penetrant liquid?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

水洗**式** does not refer to a flush toilet itself, but it refers to a method/system.

- 水: water
- 洗: wash / clean
- **式: -type**

So 水洗式 (literally "water-wash type") can refer to anything that can be washed, flushed or wiped with water. In layman terms it usually refers to a type of toilet, but in this case, it describes a type of 浸透液. The Wikipedia article you linked has a good explanation for this:

> The excess penetrant is then removed from the surface. The removal method is controlled by the type of penetrant used. **Water-washable**, solvent-removable, lipophilic post-emulsifiable, or hydrophilic post-emulsifiable are the common choices.

So:

> 浸透液は水洗式でハケ塗りとし、
>   The penetrant must be water-washable and applied with brushes, ...